# STS 3.2 -- JNDI still accessible even without register in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jndi

May be the question should be "What's the relationship between applicationContext.xml and web.xml, is it child-parent or brother-brother relationship"

Current Spring application defines JNDI in Tomcat and register the JNDI in `<resource-ref/>` in `web.xml`. There are several JNDI resource beans created in `applicationContext.xml` by `<jee:jdni-lookup>`:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource_A" jndi-name="jndi/sourceA" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource_B" jndi-name="jndi/sourceB" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource_C" jndi-name="jndi/sourceC" />
```

Now funny finding is, after comment out all `<resource-ref/>` from `web.xml`, JNDI datasources are still accessible, make me suspect the application access Tomcat by `applicationContext.xml`(where can find JNDI name) directly without through `web.xml`.

Also have to mention that such phenomenon only happens in STS3.2/tomcat-7.0.35.B.RELEASE, but not with STS2.9.2/tomcat-7.0.30.A.RELEASE

Comment: Do you have other web-app installed in the same tomcat container with the same JNDI name? If so it will be looked up by your app. Try also restarting tomcat, maybe the previous datasource hasn't fully unloaded, hence you can still discover it on JNDI

Comment: @gerrytan Thank you. I made a fresh new installation off STS and ts-server, so nothing should be cached, and once I run the application without the JNDI source in `web.xml`. But still, this version of Tomcat can allow `applicationContext.xml` to access JNDI from tomcat `context.xml` directly. Just don't know what configuration can make this the other way.